# How to click the button without JS id tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, html5-video

i'm trying to make a auto click button but this one has no id i already tried multiple script, but still not able to work

```js
document.querySelector('input[value=""]')[0].click();
```

```html
<div class="vjs-subs-caps-button vjs-menu-button vjs-menu-button-popup vjs-control vjs-button vjs-hidden"><button class="vjs-subs-caps-button vjs-menu-button vjs-menu-button-popup vjs-button" type="button" aria-disabled="false" title="Subtitles" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span aria-hidden="true" class="vjs-icon-placeholder"></span><span class="vjs-control-text" aria-live="polite">Subtitles</span></button><div class="vjs-menu"><ul class="vjs-menu-content" role="menu"><li class="vjs-menu-item vjs-texttrack-settings" role="menuitem" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="vjs-menu-item-text">subtitles settings</span><span class="vjs-control-text" aria-live="polite">, opens subtitles settings dialog</span></li><li class="vjs-menu-item vjs-selected" role="menuitemradio" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" aria-checked="true"><span class="vjs-menu-item-text">subtitles off</span><span class="vjs-control-text" aria-live="polite">, selected</span></li></ul></div></div>

<div class="community-next-episode vjs-control vjs-button"><a href="https://streamingcommunity.vip/watch/3865?e=27842"><i class="fas fa-step-forward"></i></a></div>
<button class="vjs-picture-in-picture-control vjs-control vjs-button" type="button" title="Picture-in-Picture" aria-disabled="false"><span aria-hidden="true" class="vjs-icon-placeholder"></span><span class="vjs-control-text" aria-live="polite">Picture-in-Picture</span></button>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: How about `document.querySelector('button[title="Picture-in-Picture"]')`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no id try looking for class then do:
document.querySelector(".classnamehere").click()